# Launch external jupyter qtconsole and run a script with args

Tags: python, bash, jupyter, qtconsole

I have a script  which takes one argument to run. Usually, I can run it from terminal using the standard python console with the following command:

```
$python3 myscript.py arg1 &
```

But I want to execute the script in jupyter qtconsole. It is possible to launch an external console from the terminal with this command:

```
$jupyter qtconsole &
```

I tried to launch jupyter qtconsole and run `myscript.py` with an argument `arg1`, using a similar approach:

```
$jupyter qtconsole myscript.py arg1 &
```

But it didn't worked. Is it possible to do this? How?

Comment: Not quite `jupyter`, but this works:  `ipython3  -i echo_argv.py -- testing 1 2 3`, starting a console, running `each_argv.py` and passing it the args after the `--`.  But `jupyter qtconsole` does not accept those added strings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried a similar solution, but i really need to use `jupyter qtconsole`.

Comment: In the two part console/kernel `jupyter` configuration it might not make sense to add script and argument information.  Who uses that, the console or the kernel (which is running Python)?  I wonder if there's any useful information in the `config` file.

Comment: The command `$jupyter qtconsole &` open a new console in a new window.  In fact i'm trying to write a bash script that launches the same python script with different parameters (args are for python script) and then watch the execution running in multiple console window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a new `qtconsole`:

```
In [14]: sys.argv
Out[14]: 
['/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py',
 '-f',
 '/run/user/1000/jupyter/kernel-25521.json']

In [16]: %connect_info
{
  "stdin_port": 57643,
  "key": "bcc03e84-7c43-4fbe-84d7-6c005aa37930",
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "iopub_port": 45064,
  "hb_port": 46748,
  "control_port": 39960,
  "kernel_name": "",
  "shell_port": 57532,
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256"
}

Paste the above JSON into a file, and connect with:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing <file>
or, if you are local, you can connect with just:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing kernel-25521.json
or even just:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing
if this is the most recent Jupyter kernel you have started.
```

So following that if I don

```
$ jupyter console --existing kernel-25521.json
```

I get a console that shares the kernel with the qtconsole.  If I import a module or create a variable in one, it is available in the other.

Usually when I want to run a script in `ipython` I use the `%run` magic rather than trying to include it in command line.

```
In [32]: %run echo_argv.py testing 1 2 3
['echo_argv.py', 'testing', '1', '2', '3']
```

Instead of the shell

```
$ipython3 -i echo_argv.py -- testing 1 2 3
```

To run a script without any further interaction, I use the regular `$python` invocation.  No need to involve `jupyter` or `ipython`.

```
$ python3 echo_argv.py -- testing 1 2 3
```

---

From the `qtconsole` config options:

> KernelManager.kernel_cmd
> : List
> Default: []
>
> DEPRECATED: Use kernel_name instead.
>
> The Popen Command to launch the kernel. Override this if you have a custom kernel. If kernel_cmd is specified in a configuration file, **Jupyter does not pass any arguments to the kernel**, because it cannot make any assumptions about the arguments that the kernel understands. In particular, this means that the kernel does not receive the option –debug if it given on the Jupyter command line.